# organising apps by multiple levels of folders possible?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, ios, folders

I like the idea of putting our apps in "folders" , but is there anyway we can furthur put those "folders" into "folders" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at this time. You cannot make a folder within a folder in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

As a substitute, maybe use the pages of apps on the iphone.

Comment: though the whole point is that i do not wish to have so many pages of apps